# Running firefox remotely suffers from X11 bottleneck. Why is JupyterLab (running from same Linux server) different?

Tags: firefox, jupyter-lab, x11-forwarding

I want to deploy my machine learning web app on a Linux server. I find that when I open Firefox (remotely via Mobaxterm), it is too slow due to the X11 bottleneck.

Now I have access to Jupyterlab (directly accessible from the browser) running on the same Linux server which works without any delay.

Why is it so? What can I do to run my Flask app through Firefox without the delay, same as with JupyterLab?

(Your support in editing the question to make it clear will be appreciated)

Answer (score 2):

Try out:
Put in the firefox address bar:
about:config
(click yes on the warning)
Look up:
gfx.xrender.enabled
set it from (default) False to True.

This is over ssh over local wifi....

without xrender, firefox versions of last several years would spend about 0.5-2 seconds per window sending the window content as some kind of raw, uncached image.. not terrible, but if you scroll it would just do 0.5-2 second a pop readraws as it scrolled, so not too good either. More recent versions (maybe due to webrender being on by default?) seem to send MB after MB after MB of traffic for like 30 seconds or more (don't know if it's from the page-load spinner or what), once the page does load it actually scrolls fast (the X server must have a local copy of the page content) but it takes far to long to get there.

xrender, it sends pixmaps to the local X server too, but uses a surprisingly low amount of traffic doing so.  Pages like stackoverflow and lighter comic sites load indistinguishable from a local copy of firefox; sites with heavy graphics may spend a second or two sending the large graphics, but then they're in the local X server and the page scrolls around and operates at full speed.

Running xrender if you run firefox locally doesn't seem to cause any harm either (i.e. you don't have to turn the setting on and off depending on if you are using firefox remotely or locally.)

Enjoy the speed!

Cheers!

--Henry